# Question about Julia type syntax: Why is Array{Int32, 1} <: Array{Integer, 1} false?

Tags: julia

In Julia,

```
Array{Int32, 1} <: Array{Integer, 1}
```

evaluates to `false`, but

```
Array{Int32, 1} <: (Array{T, 1} where T <: Integer)
```

evaluates to `true` because `Int32 <: Integer` is true.

In my mind, the first and second expressions communicate the same idea and should evaluate equivalently. Furthermore, the first expression is less cluttered. Is there a reason why Julia's syntax evaluates the former as false but the latter as true?  Is there something deep and good about this behavior or is this an oversight in how Arrays/the type system were developed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference between `Array{Integer, 1}` and `Array{T, 1} where T <: Integer` is that the former is a concrete type, while the later is an abstract type. The reason this makes a difference is that you can make a variable with type `Array{Integer, 1}`. This is a potentially heterogeneous array, so it has to be implemented as an array of pointers (so slow and heap allocated). With this in mind, it is clear why `Array{Int32, 1} <: Array{Integer, 1}=false`. If we write a method for the specific type `Array{Integer, 1}`, that can't be specialized since it is already a concrete type, and we would segfault when we run it on an `Array{Int32, 1}` which has a completely different data format (inline elements).

Comment: That makes sense!  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

See [Parametric Composite Types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Parametric-Composite-Types-1) from the manual.

> Concrete `Point` types with different values of `T` are never subtypes of each other:

```
julia> Point{Float64} <: Point{Int64}
false

julia> Point{Float64} <: Point{Real}
false
```

> **Warning**
>   This last point is very important: even though `Float64 <: Real` we **DO NOT** have `Point{Float64} <: Point{Real}`.
>
> In other words, in the parlance of type theory, ***Julia's type parameters are invariant***, rather than being [covariant (or even contravariant)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).
>
> This is for practical reasons: while any instance of `Point{Float64}` may conceptually be like an instance of `Point{Real}` as well, the two types have different representations in memory:
>
> - An instance of `Point{Float64}` can be represented compactly and efficiently as an immediate pair of 64-bit values;
> - An instance of `Point{Real}` must be able to hold any pair of instances of `Real`. Since objects that are instances of `Real` can be of arbitrary size and structure, in practice an instance of `Point{Real}` must be represented as a pair of pointers to individually allocated `Real` objects.

Answer (score 0):

There were [discussions](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/reason-behind-designing-parametric-types-as-invariant/18971/3) about making the behaviour you described as default, but they finally reached consensus that the current might be better.

Basically it is a syntax choice of what `Vector{Integer}` means. There are three types of vairance to choose from:

```
julia> Vector{Int32} <: (Vector{T} where T <: Integer)
true

julia> Vector{Any} <: (Vector{T} where T >: Integer)
true

julia> Vector{Integer} <: (Vector{T} where {T >: Integer, T <: Integer})
true
```

The three types of variance correspond to three different operations about the variable. Covariance for read, contravariance for write, and invariance for both. For example in Rust, `&'a T` is covariant about `T`, because you can only read from it, while `&'a mut T` is invariant since it can be both read and written. If ever there being a "write-only" type, contravarance would be a sane default. Given variables in Julia are both read and writable, defaulting to invariance looks a good choice.